# Как получить тип класса в typescript?

Tags: typescript

Есть класс:

```
class Test {
  ...
}
```

Как получить его тип в другом файле?

Пробовал:

1)

```
export type { Test };
```

2. 

```
type testType = typeof Test;
export type {testType};
```

Хочу сделать первым вариантом. Что-то работать не хочет. Со вторым получается, но не "оверхед" ли это?

Comment: Так же как и все в JS, без приставки `type`, просто `export {Test}`

Comment: Там суть такая. Мне нужно экспортировать исключительно тип. Сделал так: `export type {Test}`, в другом файле `import type {Test}` и потом: `type provider = typeof Test | "ТУТ ДРУГИЕ ТИПЫ"`. Но вот правильно ли сделал... Этого не знаю.

Comment: А разве нельзя это просто смешать [примерно так](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeAoa0BmBXAdgBQCUAXNAG4D2AlgCZoC+6zSAngA7zQDKVAtvAQAPFAF5oAcmxUqk6AB8pAIzAAnSenZdoAETBIw0CRixhyARkzRl5CG37KqIFui2duHNVQr14a4zhEFCU+QREQvQMwNzx8YCQaKnwcWUIOci8fPzViU2gAegLoADoy13QZKkJ8eAB3IOQSYiA)

Comment: Пытался сделать так `type provider = Test | SomeText | Data`, правда в другом файле, экспортировав предварительно, как `export type`. Без typeof не работало, смешал так: type provider = `typeof Test | SomeText | Data` (SomeText и Data) - типы, с ними, скорее всего, работать будет. А вот с классом были проблемы.

Comment: Ааа, если я правильно понял, [надо типа такого](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeAoa0BmBXAdgBQCUAXNAG4D2AlgCZoC+6zSAngA7zQDKVAtvAQAPFAF5oAcmxUqk6AB8pAIzAAnSenZdoAETBIw0CRixhyARkzRl5CG37KqIFui2duHNVQr14a42hCbXgqbDhEJGJFXgEheFEY-UM3PHxgJBoqfBxZQg5yLx8-NWJTaBpsYI8w6A5jMQlpAgys-Elo8qxgbORocWh8eAB3OpJoAHoJ6B78PqRyBGRrLCQAOjSSa2ZmdBkqQiWooA)

Comment: Правильно поняли)) Так и сделал, только `typeof Test` в скобки не брал. Спасибо, значит так делают...

Comment: я сомневаюсь в правильности применения `typeof`, ниже пример

Comment: [Кстати так работает](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVaBTAHgF3QOwBMYJsAnASzwHMA+aAbwChpoSxtzhoAjMUgLmgBGaAB9oAJjHQAzNAC8w5tAAOglMuDw8JUgFdg2eKQAUa6CgCUDZS2wALchAB0KhauUBfZVXTYAIuxgJpbqNiwspH56pHjQDk6uXozejABmeniG5Nqs8AC26ADq5A7wetgAwtq6BkamwILYAJ4q6PBpcIih0ABu8OQE4dBaOtjQcYrAzryk0AD088LSUuIymjXjlGxZ6O546ADuI0gA5GmIp6Kns6c0JueXlhtj0ARB7tvYYLvOvgFBEIpRhAA). Но я поискал это применение во всех lib-файлах. С универсальными типами не нашел, [здесь пример](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L3807). Так что лучше отдельным интерфейсом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если конструктор передается в параметры, воспользуйтесь синтаксисом интерфейса

```
// Предположим у нас универсальный класс
class Foo<T extends string> {
  static bar: 1 | 2 | 3 = 1
  p: T
  constructor(p: T) {
    this.p = p
  }
  getData(): T {
    return this.p
  }
}

// Объявляем конструктор
interface FooConstructor<T extends string> {
  // Тут же можем объявить статические свойства
  bar: 1 | 2 | 3
  new(p: T): Foo<T>
}

// Используем
function someWithConstructor(c: FooConstructor<'foo' | 'bar'>): void {
  // Здесь имеем доступ к статическим свойствам
  const n = c.bar // 1 | 2 | 3
  const instance = new c('foo')
  const data = instance.getData() // return: "foo" | "bar"
}

// А эти варианты смотрите в Playground
function someWithoutConstructor_0(c: typeof Foo<'foo'|'bar'>)): void {
  // Error
}
function someWithoutConstructor_1(c: typeof (Foo<'foo' | 'bar'>)): void {
  // Error
}
function someWithoutConstructor_2(c: (typeof Foo)<'foo'|'bar'>): void {
  // Error
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEnwQQBEEVhBBYQR+EEHwghuEEYNhBAcIIHhBSGEQUgvCCAMIIIIgeBGgTCDSQlHKAyIAYNIggnCCiBcIMqSQFADGAGwCGAZ1GgAYgHtpAHgAqoAKYAPAC7KAdgBMJo9QCcAlloDmAPlABvXqFAHh64-1AAjYYYBcoAIygAH1AAJkDQAGZQAF4-O1AABx8FOP5pLQNDAFd+dWlDAApE0AUAShs4+3UAC2NRADp46IS4gF84s2V1ABEnYXySpPL7e0NOzMMtUGrahtbeNt4QUEA8EEBGEEApEEB5EEpkTegcDkQCEkAhEEhcDhPESF5TTUMAM2F+ZSlZAGE0jOzcw0UVDTaPQOIymSxDUBLQBEILgTqA0NBQFh0PtQIgNtsMCcGKBTkQThhAOIg0BIHAwiJIlEQrFOlCIcQ83j8YVCQXCcS0ygA7oUkgM3vIFBZ5rxFmBABggJCQjEA7CC4VEAWjRgAkQDCrRAcQjQE68B6ZLQ5YxpBzSAC2ygA6sZqp90kYfnl8vwfDJpLbvjk8nIAOQPWTegLexneiz8gBu0mMOghS0A6CCwEk47DQVGwRCnXDwTi4k74okksk4SnU2lELApL7qUCTGL8OqMyFgfxBVkRCt20CmRwG14xTlc0D8fK+-0ldsGUA6XpNLvqYQ9uodbq9fqN0CjdTjLQ+ABEfukO7CO8ZO5FoqWgAQQUAnWFo2AUFaAChBxYBEEEAWCDi3X6w3G0Rmy3WlU0iZOo7r2p6hgAPoAAxOj46gAJ7xMo0gPAKPr7gGQaeCGJThpG0a2PYqQdjWg71p4a7NiEYTssRladna84vE0-aDsOmFjvYs7Mcoi6dD0c79CKeoGs4v7-la1TAaBlZZBBkG+HBUxIShaH5K6GH+oGwahvhUYQiRE5kXWDZLNRrZ0YODE8T2rHcuxI7SN6XGMd2Lz8cuQljm0ok-pMf7mlJQEgWB8m-JBwTKfkiHIahAolFpzk6ThoY+BGBlEdZpFNKZlHmSytHjlWtksX2DlDk5LlxKVfFLoJfQ+eeYCAEggiAysiaAEIgoAYKAJLYqAdKQBgRAEHCGBSigDAyogdKDbFakADSED1mxakNpwwIS9CgIAsiBXENoCACIgRCsNwgCiIKAgjGG4dQAFR1DodTqKIQA)

Возможно и есть вариант использовать `typeof`, но я не встречал это в файлах `lib.*.d.ts`. Смотрите, к примеру, как объявлены конструкторы в "node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts" для `String`, строка 517.